# unable to start RecyclerView in fragment ( Release Build ) but works perfect in ( Debug Build )

Tags: java, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

i don't know what is wrong but i was creating this app on debug and nothing wrong with it but when i tried to test release build i get app crash in every fragment that has a query adapter with RecyclerView ! i really don't know if it was something wrong with my code why it does't crash in debug build ?
anyway here is fragment

```
public class light_home_fragment extends Fragment implements v1.m.a.t.Adapters.FavAdapter.OnFavSelectedListener {

            private Query mQuery;
            private static final int LIMIT = 50;
            private FavAdapter FavAdapter;
            private FirebaseFirestore mFireStore;
            private RecyclerView recyclerView;

            public light_home_fragment() {
            }

            private String[] values = {
                            "Chef","Grocery"
            };

            private int[] images = {
                            R.drawable.chef,R.drawable.market_small
            };

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_light_home_fragment, container, false);
                        GridView homeGridView = view.findViewById(R.id.HomeGridView);
                        HomeGrideAdapter homeGridAdapter = new HomeGrideAdapter(getActivity(),values,images);
                        homeGridView.setAdapter(homeGridAdapter);
                        homeGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                            int position, long id) {
                                                if(position==0) {
                                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DashBoardActivity.class);
                                                            String GetExtra = "rClicked";
                                                            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", GetExtra);
                                                            startActivity(intent);
                                                }
                                                else if(position==1)
                                                {
                                                            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DashBoardActivity.class);
                                                            String GetExtra = "mClicked";
                                                            intent.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", GetExtra);
                                                            startActivity(intent);
                                                }
                                    }
                        });

                        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerFav);
                        mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
                        startFav();

                        return view;
            }


            private void startFav(){
                        FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        assert currentUser != null;
                        final String UserPhone = currentUser.getPhoneNumber();
                        assert UserPhone != null;
                        mQuery = mFireStore.collection("Users").
                                        document(UserPhone).collection("favList")
                                        .limit(LIMIT);

                        FavAdapter = new FavAdapter(mQuery,this) {
                                    @Override
                                    protected void onDataChanged() {
                                                if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                                                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                }else {
                                                            recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                                }
                                    }
                        };
                        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(FavAdapter);
            }


            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                        super.onStart();

            }

            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                        super.onStop();
                        if (FavAdapter != null) {
                                    FavAdapter.stopListening();
                        }
            }

            @Override
            public void onResume(){
                        super.onResume();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFavSelected(DocumentSnapshot fav) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(RDetailActivity.KEY_BID, fav.getId());
                        startActivity(intent);
            }
}
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class FavAdapter extends FirestoreAdapter<FavAdapter.FavViewHolder> {

    public interface OnFavSelectedListener {
        void onFavSelected(DocumentSnapshot business);
    }
    private FavAdapter.OnFavSelectedListener mListener;
    protected FavAdapter(Query query, FavAdapter.OnFavSelectedListener listener) {
        super(query);
        mListener = listener;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public FavAdapter.FavViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        return new FavAdapter.FavViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fav_item, parent, false));
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FavAdapter.FavViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(getSnapshot(position), mListener);
    }

    public interface OnFavAdapterSelectedListener {
        void onFavSelected(DocumentSnapshot Fav);
    }

    static class FavViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView FavImage;
        TextView FavText;
        FavViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            FavImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FavImg);
            FavText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FavText);
        }
        void bind(final DocumentSnapshot snapshot,
                  final FavAdapter.OnFavSelectedListener listener ) {
            FavJava fav = snapshot.toObject(FavJava.class);
            assert fav != null;
            FavText.setText(fav.getName());
            if(FavImage != null) {
                Glide.with(FavImage.getContext())
                    .load(fav.getImage_Url())
                    .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.t_logo_new)
                        .error(R.drawable.pizza_monster)
                    )
                    .into(FavImage);
            }
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.onFavSelected(snapshot);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and this is view modal

```
package v1.m.a.t.Java;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.IgnoreExtraProperties;

@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class FavJava {
            private String id;
            private String name;
            private String image_Url;
            public FavJava(){}
            public FavJava(String id,String name, String image_Url){
                        this.id = id;
                        this.name = name;
                        this.image_Url = image_Url;
            }

            public String getId() {
                        return id;
            }

            public void setId(String id) {
                        this.id = id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                        return name;
            }

            public void setName(String name) {
                        this.name = name;
            }

            public String getImage_Url() {
                        return image_Url;
            }

            public void setImage_Url(String image_Url) {
                        this.image_Url = image_Url;
            }
}
```

error log

```
Process: v1.m.a.t, PID: 7420
    java.lang.RuntimeException: No properties to serialize found on class v1.m.a.t.b.d
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.u0.n$a.<init>()
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.u0.n.a()
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.u0.n.a()
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.u0.n.b()
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.u0.n.a()
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.i.a()
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.d0.a()
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.i.a()
        at com.google.firebase.firestore.d0.a()
        at v1.m.a.t.a.h$a.a()
        at v1.m.a.t.a.h.a()
        at v1.m.a.t.a.h.b()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.a()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$g.a()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.a()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.a()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.b()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$v.d()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$c.a()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.a()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.e()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2()
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure()
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.a()
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure()
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:900)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure()
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure()
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20151)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2594)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1549)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1841)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1437)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7397)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at andro
04-28 19:55:44.118 3973-8141/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.product_ship = true
04-28 19:55:44.118 3973-8141/? E/android.os.Debug: ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
04-28 19:55:44.118 3973-8141/? E/android.os.Debug: sys.mobilecare.preload = false
04-28 19:55:44.193 8143-8143/? E/Zygote: v2
04-28 19:55:44.198 8143-8143/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-28 19:55:44.498 8165-8165/? E/Zygote: v2
04-28 19:55:44.503 8165-8165/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-28 19:55:44.593 6099-10195/? E/art: invalid stream - problem with parameter iterator in /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk:classes3.dex for method void com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(int)
04-28 19:55:44.833 6099-10195/? E/art: invalid stream - problem with parameter iterator in /data/app/com.google.android.gms-1/base.apk:classes3.dex for method void com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.setSoWriteTimeout(int)
04-28 19:55:44.873 8210-8210/? E/Zygote: v2
04-28 19:55:44.878 8210-8210/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-28 19:55:44.968 8228-8228/? E/Zygote: v2
04-28 19:55:44.973 8228-8228/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-28 19:55:45.113 8250-8250/? E/Zygote: v2
04-28 19:55:45.118 8250-8250/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-28 19:55:45.968 8288-8288/? E/Zygote: v2
04-28 19:55:45.973 8288-8288/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-28 19:55:46.248 8288-8288/? E/HealthDataStore: disconnectService: Context instance is invalid
04-28 19:55:46.393 8309-8309/? E/Zygote: v2
04-28 19:55:46.393 8309-8309/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-28 19:55:47.518 8331-8331/? E/Zygote: v2
04-28 19:55:47.518 8331-8331/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
04-28 19:55:47.608 8331-8343/? E/SPPClientService: ShipBuild Binary : True
```

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: @AlexMamo ok i uploaded logcat

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution

i forgot to add
`-keep package v1.m.a.t.Java.** { *; }`
inside proguard-rules

omg i thought i were lost :)

for complete answer i changed the modal items from private to public , like below

`public String id;
            public String name;
            public String image_Url;`